# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, pandas-groupby

I have 2 different datasets(namely first_set and df) and I would like to merge them together. Here is the first problem that I solved:

[image]

The 2 columns are converted to the date format using the following code block:

```
df['new_date'] = df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Hours'].astype(str).replace(r'\s-\s\d+$','', regex=True)
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new_date'])
```

After that I appended the dataset to the other:

```
final = first_set.append(df)
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to group dataset monthly, it is a simple procedure with the following code blocks:

```
final= final.set_index("new_date")
final_2= final.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="m")).sum()
```

But the error that I add the title occurs and I couldn't handle it. Could you please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like some of your data are strings and some are timestamps. You should make sure all values in the same column are of the same dtype

Comment: Exactly, the error indicates that case. I am trying to convert string to timestamps or timestamps to string.

Comment: why don't you convert the date/time column in *both* datasets to datetime *before* appending one to the other?